# How to use enter(), exit() and update with horizontal "stacked" chart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a pseudo-stacked, horizontal chart. I saw pseudo because it mimics a stacked chart but is not really multiple stacked values, but rather 3 different values that add up to a total of 100%. I'm not sure what the name of this kind of chart is.

Anyways, I'm trying to figure out how to get the `enter()` and `exit()` and updating to work for the chart when the data changes. I have this jsfiddle as an example

http://jsfiddle.net/Uhrgt/

The svg structure starts like this:

```
<svg class="chart" width="756" height="50">
    <g transform="translate(0,0)" width="73.6">
        <rect height="50" width="224" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 255);"></rect>
        <text x="113" y="25" dy=".35em">30%</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(75,0)" width="451">
        <rect height="50" width="451" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></rect>
        <text x="226" y="25" dy=".35em">60%</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(529.2000122070312,0)" width="224.8">
        <rect height="50" width="73" style="fill: rgb(128, 0, 128);"></rect>
        <text x="37" y="25" dy=".35em">10%</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

And after the data changes, it looks like this:

```
<svg class="chart" width="756" height="50">
    <g transform="translate(0,0)" width="73.6">
        <rect height="50" width="224" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 255);"></rect>
        <text x="113" y="25" dy=".35em">30%</text>
        <rect height="50" width="73" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 255);"></rect>
        <text x="37" y="25" dy=".35em">10%</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(75,0)" width="451">
        <rect height="50" width="451" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></rect>
        <text x="226" y="25" dy=".35em">60%</text>
        <rect height="50" width="451" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></rect>
        <text x="226" y="25" dy=".35em">60%</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(529,0)" width="224.8">
        <rect height="50" width="73" style="fill: rgb(128, 0, 128);"></rect>
        <text x="37" y="25" dy=".35em">10%</text>
        <rect height="50" width="224" style="fill: rgb(128, 0, 128);"></rect>
        <text x="113" y="25" dy=".35em">30%</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The `rects` and `texts` are getting created again, and the old ones are not being removed. There are two problems here:

1. The `rect`s are being duplicated for some reason. I'm not sure why the `exit()` isn't working for them.
2. The `text`s are being duplicated because I have `text.exit().remove()` commented out at the moment, but uncommenting it results in an error for some reason.

What the proper way to use the enter, update and exit functions for when you create a chart and then later update the data for them? I have been following many online examples and thought I was using the correct syntax but it's not working properly obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the issues you're seeing is that you have your `text` and `rect` elements grouped in `g` elements. You need to handle enter, update and exit selections *only for the `g` elements*. Everything else hangs off of that. This implies that you need to save the enter selection for the `g` elements and then append the other elements to that.

The structure would look like this:

```
 var barEnter = bar.enter().append('g');
 barEnter.append("rect");
 barEnter.append("text");
```

For the update selection:

```
 bar.transition()...
 bar.select("rect").transition()...
 bar.select("text").transition()...
```

For the exit selection, you just need to remove the `g` elements because that will also remove everything contained within them:

```
 bar.exit().remove();
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Uhrgt/1/).

Comment: +1 The enter/update/exit selection off of a `svg:g` can trip many folks. I [blogged](http://www.fernoftheandes.com/blog/blog005/index.html) about this to solidify it in my mind...so, I am passing it on to others here. And looking back at it, I should probably stress the importance of keying the data.

Comment: Both of your explanations REALLY helped a lot. I figured it out. Thank you http://jsfiddle.net/Uhrgt/5/

Comment: By the way, is the only way to do a transition() on update, but not on `enter()`, is to use the same methods in two places (as see in my updated jsfiddle above)? The calculations I do for the `g` width and translation and the `text` position I use in two places. One at `enter()` and then again later using a transition. Is that the only way to accomplish it?

Comment: No, the enter selection actually merges the appended elements into the update selection. So technically all you have to do with the enter selection is append the elements. All the attributes can be set on the update selection.

Comment: But if you have a `transition()` on the update section, when I load the page, there is a transition of the elements as they initially move into position, where I would rather them appear instantaneously in their position and only do a transition when the data changes on an update. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can certainly set all the attributes (without transition) on the enter selection.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this, but how come when I add a viewBox to the chart (to work with a variable-width (responsive) container), the individual elements render in the correct place but exist outside the container? http://i.imgur.com/UyVq8FI.jpg  http://jsfiddle.net/Jakobud/Uhrgt/7/

Comment: It looks like you're setting the width on the `g` element instead of the `rect` now. That doesn't really work -- set it on the `rect` elements instead.