# Rectangles not resizing properly with scale/width change

Tags: d3.js

Select 'name' and then 'focus' setting for the attached fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/HVkyL/.  For some reason the rectangles don't resize with the width change.  Any ideas?   I'm using a group for rect and text:

```
gEnter = group.enter()
         .append("g")
         .attr("class", "grow")
         .style("fill", "blue")
          .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + xRange(d.start) + "," +     yRange(d[axes.yAxis]) + ")"; });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the enter/update/exit pattern for elements under a `svg:g` group is the star of the last two days. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947498/how-to-use-enter-exit-and-update-with-horizontal-stacked-chart#23950783), for example, for a similar answer by Lars, my comments below the answer (with a link to my blog post on the subject). I believe this is the pattern that you want in your redraw function:

```
...
gEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "rectband");

group.selectAll(".rectband")
    .attr("width", function (d) {return xRange(d.width)})
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .style("opacity", .5) // set the element opacity
    .style("stroke", "black"); // set the line colour;

gEnter.append("text")
    .attr("class", "textband");

group.selectAll(".textband")
    .style("fill", "black")
    .text(function (d) {return (d.name);})
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + (2) + "," + (13) + ")";
    });
...
```

Please also note that you were using the same CSS class for rectangles and text.

Here is the updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5KV45/).

Comment: Thank you so much. I was really stuck with this, I thought is was down to the enter/update/exit pattern but couldn't find the solution.  Yours works great.

Comment: YMW. Please accept the answer then so that others know this was the right solution. Thanks :)